# Realistic Bacta Tank Fluid

Tags: internal-consistency, near-future, medicine

Ever since I watched *Star Wars* I have always been fascinated with the Bacta Tank: that tank with the funky blue liquid Luke Skywalker was submerged in.
[image: Luke Skywalker in a Bacta Tank]

But now I'm wondering could it become reality? The basic premise of a Bacta Tank is: a tank of liquid (Bacta) that when a patient is fully submerged causes rapid healing and regeneration (judging by the films it cant regenerate full limbs or organs so it probably just regenerates what it can and mends the rest) allowing some one with rather severe to be stabilized and fully healed in the time span of a few days to weeks.

Could modern or near future science be able to create a liquid similar to Bacta? The main requirements of the liquid would be: to induce rapid healing by cellular regeneration and mending to allow a severely injured patient to make a full recovery (full as in not dead. Depending on the injuries some body parts might not fully regenerate)

Note: not too worried about time. So if the liquid takes longer than a few weeks that's fine.

I'm going with the assumption that Bacta can heal injuries quickly it cannot regenerate full limbs.

Comment: Bacta = Neosporin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the "near-future" future requirement hurts this possibility. We don't know how to treat a lot of the things the bacta tank addresses to begin with even using the full extent of modern medicine.

#### Here are some techniques that at least have a basis in current research (ie no super nanobots):

- There are a few proteins that aid the body's natural tissue healing process in mammals: for instance [MG53](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/03/160302135149.htm) and [thrombospondin 2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10571734). The tank could contain bacteria that produce versions of these proteins altered to be more effective, as well as a soup of simple sugars to fuel the bacteria's production. Proteins that require energized ATP to function could be supplied by a different strain of bacteria. These proteins have been shown to accelerate healing and remove scars in mice; there's probably a good analog in humans.
- The mixture could be programmed to the genotype of the person submerged in it by a medical technician. Engineered stem cells float in the fluid until they find a spot including inflammation. They then specialize to become skin cells or immune system T-cells, aiding in closing wounds and fighting infection.
- The mixture could contain topical antibiotics (if there are bacteria in it as well they need to have antibiotic resistance)
- The mixture contain cells that produce [bacteriophages](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/bacteriophage-phage-293) to target foreign bacteria that they find. This is more precise than antibiotics and has fewer side effects
- The temperature of the fluid can be controlled to help the body regulate internal temperature, and the fluid can be made to conduct heat very well to speed up this process.
- The fluid can contain [Chemical Permeation Enhancers](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37900-0) to make the skin more permeable, allowing introduction of water and various anti-inflammatory or [analgesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analgesic) drugs.
- The fluid can contain topical antivenins to counteract snake/insect bites, poison ivy/nettle burns, or even biological/chemical weapons.
- You can breathe a higher concentration or pressure of oxygen through a tube, allowing for accelerated healing and reduction of pain, inflammation and headaches.

The main thing with these though is that they only target the outside of the body. What if you have internal bleeding or broken bones?

The fundamental problem here is that if you have a fluid that can fix internal damage, the ideal method of delivery for it is not "dunk the patient in a big vat full of medicine until they get better." The fluid would have to enter the body at some point in order to function, and I don't see how it's going to do that.

#### You could probably treat a good number of conditions with a relatively near-future bacta tank:

- Burns
- Scarring
- Cuts & abrasions
- Topical infections
- Skin fungus
- Hypothermia
- Hyperthermia (overheating, usually due to fever)
- Rash or inflammation
- Snakebites/insect bites/poisonous space monster bites
- Dehydration
- Headaches
- Sleep deprivation (because hey, you're floating in a tank for hours)

#### Things it won't treat (not a complete list for obvious reasons):

- Broken bones
- Ruptured organs
- Brain damage
- Cancer
- Pneumonia (if you're having lung trouble breathing through a tube could cause problems)
- Radiation poisoning
- Food poisoning
- Pretty much any other type of poisoning
- Genetic diseases
- Psychological conditions
- Claustrophobia (duh)
- Fear of drowning (duh)
- Anaphylactic shock
- Ordinary shock
- Blood loss (it won't treat this without some other equipment providing blood)
- Hair loss
- Heart disease
- Diabetes
- Obesity
- Bruises or internal bleeding
- Shrapnel damage
- Missing limbs
- Missing organs
- Blindness
- Deafness

...You get the picture. It's not a panacea, but it is a valuable piece of medical equipment.

Comment: I wonder, would it be possible to provide oxygenation, hydration and nutrition with the same fluid? Using it as a breathing fluid seems possible, but I think a patient would need some sort of TPN to spend in the tank longer then a day.

Comment: @Cumehtar not all nutrients are water-soluble. Vitamin A got instance would precipitate out of the liquid. Also the sheer number of unique nutrients we need would be hard to deal with. Breathing fluid is infeasible since the lungs aren't strong enough to cycle anything dense enough for us to float in, and there are a lot of problems preventing us from breathing liquids. You could maybe get 1.5 out of 3: hydration and partial nutrition.

Comment: floating in a tub for long enough with a regulated food input can definitely help with diabetes or obesity. not cure them, but help. some psychological conditions will also be greatly helped by the isolation it offers, and the oxygen poisoning can also help with anxiety. Maybe adding some iodine could also help with radiation poisoning. some heart disease can be eased with the support water offer to blood flow in the legs. so there is a lot of things in your "won't treat" list that will be partly treated at least.

Answer (score 7):

We know that human healing can be accelerated by large doses of oxygen, this is usually achieved by high pressures as in [Hyperbaric Oxygen Treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaric_medicine), but it could be delivered by extremely heavily oxygenated [breathing fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_breathing) of some form. Given the apparent limitations of Bacta I would suggest that is just such an oxygenated fluid, carrying several times as much oxygen as usual to the cells of a body suspended in it. This would explain the accelerated but not miraculous scope of the healing in such tanks.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Bacta, in Star Wars, is basically the equivalent of healing magic. And that's fine for Star Wars, because it's soft sci-fi anyways, and draws heavily on classic high fantasy for inspiration. But here's a few uses of bacta you left out: Regeneration of large tissue loss without scars (chucks of skin, internal organs, etc., as long as part of the organ is there), the ability to cure every disease (except for those which cause bacta allergies), the ability to flush every toxin, full stasis when necessary, and (this is the kicker) can be applied to literally every alien in the franchise. The stuff can cure cancer and regenerate nerve damage. Like I said, healing magic.

As for something which just induces accelerate healing with modern technology- that's a bit more possible. A combination of steroids and the right diet should do the job, but there'd be a cost involve. Generally, there's a reason why your body heals at it's own pace, artificially inducing rapid healing probably has a cost on the human lifespan.